# Equation involving determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am given three square matrices $A,B$ and $C$ such that $$B=\begin{pmatrix}N&\varepsilon^T\\\eta&A\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }C=\begin{pmatrix}N-1&\varepsilon^T\\\eta&A\end{pmatrix}.$$ Here $N$ is an integer and $\varepsilon,\eta$ are columns.

In my lecture in a proof we have used that $$\det(t^{1/2}C-t^{-1/2}C^T)-\det(t^{1/2}B-t^{-1/2}B^T)=(t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2})\det(t^{1/2}A-t^{-1/2}A^T).$$

Is somebody able to explain why this holds?

Comment: What is $t$ here?

Comment: A variable, the result of each determinant is an element in $\mathbb{Z}[t^{-1/2},t^{1/2}]$.

Comment: The result is false. Try with $A=I_n$, $\varepsilon = 0$ and $\eta = 0$. However, the following result is true: $$\det(t^{1/2}C-t^{-1/2}C^T)-\det(t^{1/2}B-t^{-1/2}B^T) = (t^{-1/2}-t^{1/2})\det(t^{1/2}A-t^{-1/2}A^T).$$ If you have any conditions on $A$ let us know.

Comment: I am absolutly sorry! That was a typo. Your equation is what I wanted. Really sorry that you made some 'senseless' calculations! But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, we write $M(t)=t^{1/2}M-t^{-1/2}M^T$ for any square matrix.

Now, $C(t) = B(t) - (t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2})E_{1,1}$ where $E_{1,1}$ has only one 1 in the upper-left corner and zeros elsewhere.

Hence, by expanding the determinant of $C(t)$ along the first column ([Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion)), you easily get: $$\det\left(C(t)\right) = - \left(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}\right)\det\left(A(t)\right) +\det\left(B(t)\right).$$

By rearranging, you get the formula you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I don't get you Laplace argument. The entry $(1,1)$ is $t^{1/2}N-t^{-1/2}N-(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2})$ and so the first term in Laplace's sum is $(t^{1/2}N-t^{-1/2}N-(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2}))\det A(t)$. But this is different from yours, isn't it?

Comment: Expand both $C(t)$ and $B(t)$ using Laplace expansion on the first column. As both matrices are equal for all coordinates except the $(1,1)$ coordinate, the sums corresponding to the expansions will be the same except for the first term: $$ \det\left(C(t)\right) = (N-1)(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2})\det\left(A(t)\right) + ... $$ and $$\det\left(B(t)\right) = N(t^{1/2}-t^{-1/2})\det\left(A(t)\right) + ... $$